# How to construct a query without triggering it with activeRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this code:

```
def build_query(options)
  query = User
  query = query.where('first_condition')
  query = query.where('second_condition')
  query = query.where('items.category_id = ?', category) if (options[:category])
  if options[:location]
    query = query.where('users.location = ?', options[:location])
  end
  query = query.order('users.current_sign_in_at DESC')
  query = query.limit(MAX_RESULTS)
  return query
end
```

Unfortunately, a request is trigerred each time I do `query = query.where(...)`

I could just chain all where clauses (`where().where()...`), but then how do I keep my `if`s ?

Is there a way to tell ActiveRecord not to trigger the query ?

Answer (score 2):

You can collect all conditions in `conditions` variable:

```
conditions = {}
conditions.merge('first_condition') if ...
conditions.merge('second_condition') if ...
# snip

User.where(conditions).order('users.current_sign_in_at DESC').limit(MAX_RESULTS)
```